# Pyspark-Kafka java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-kafka

We are getting a **CAST EXCEPTION** when trying to pass the offsets from Pyspark code to Kafka DStream.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2938.createDirectStreamWithMessageHandler.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

We have upgraded from Python 2.7 to 3.6 and for the upgrade we had to change the **long() to int()** under the Offset function, on doing the change we are getting the CAST exception!!!

```
kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc=spark_streaming_ctx,
                                           topics="Test",
                                           kafkaParams={
                                               "BROKER": "BROKER_LIST"),
                                               "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"},
                                           fromOffsets=self.Offset(spark, "TOPIC"),
                                           messageHandler="messageHandler")

def Offset(in_spark, in_topic_list):
    offsets_map = {}
    offsets_map[Topic] = int(offset[1])  # convert long to int for Python3X
    return offsets_map
```

We also tried use the future library https://pypi.org/project/past/, yet we didn't have any luck.

Python : 3.6
Pyspark : 2.4
Kafka : 2.1.0

Comment: did you try with `float(offset[1])` ?

Comment: yes @flo tried that too, no luck with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your spark submit code in case if you are using 0_10 version streaming jar file You will get above error. 0_10 version will not support python. Instead of 0_10 you can use 0_8 Kafka version.

Kafka 0_8 Version will accept the integer offset value.

Could you please refer below document.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue passing the corresponding jar made the trick.